# relative paths for shared libraries

Tags: linker, g++, java-native-interface, shared

I'm working with JNI. I have a wrapper library (wrapper.so) that uses two shared libraries: one.so and two.so

Everything works fine. All *.so are in the lib folder, inside the program folder.

The problem is, if I copy this folder to another computer I get linking problems.

Let's say I run this on a machine user2 (/home/user2/program), and I compiled in a machine user1 (/home/user1/program), I get the linking error:

UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/user1/program/lib/one.so

How I can make the linking of the libraries relative to the parent program folder (like, search for this_foler/lib ??

I'm compiling like:

```
g++ -c -o src/wrapper.o src/wrapper.c
g++ -shared -o wrapper.so src/wrapper.o one.so two.so
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How I can make the linking of the libraries relative to the parent program folder

Depends on your operating system. On Linux, this will probably work:

```
g++ -shared -o wrapper.so -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' src/wrapper.o one.so two.so
```

Note: single quotes are *important* in above command.

Comment: @Rockskull if the answer works, you are supposed to accept it, vote it up, or both. If you don't some people may not bother answering your questions nex time.

Comment: Sorry. New to the Stack Overflow. I accept it, but I can't vote it up.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Do you know the corresponding command for intel compiler? Thanks.

Comment: @xslittlegrass The `-Wl,...` syntax is pretty universal, and should be supported by `icc` as well, at least as far as I can tell from https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/linux_clusters/man/icc.txt

Comment: I couldn't make it work from makefile. had -Wl,-rpath=RIGIN/../Lib output. using double $$ solved it for me.

So, if this is in a makefile, use -Wl,-rpath='$$ORIGIN'